# text-align and margin CSS properties are not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass, ionic3

*.scss*

```
div.playlist {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.playlist {
    span {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .span-icon {
        padding-bottom: 50px !important;
    }
}
div.playlist span:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
}
```

*.html*

```
<div class="playlist">
  <span class="span-icon"><ion-icon [name]="data.icon"></ion-icon></span>
  <span>{{data.text}}</span>
  <img [src]="data.imageUrl" [alt]="data.text" />
</div>
```

*Out Put*

[image]

Now I need as shown below.Please don't consider about the different `icon` type and the `text`.I just need this.I need a responsive `top right` and the `bottom right` appearance of the `icon` and `text`.I have tried with `text-align: right` and the `margin` properties.But you know that approach is not responsive on different view ports.So can you help me to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: `position: absolute;` and `top: 0; right: 0;`

Comment: Can you put that as an answer with more details according to my `css` above? Exactly not clear what you mentioned. @Doomenik

Comment: This is pretty basic, just add what I wrote to your  `.span-icon` and remove that padding, I think its unecessary

Comment: I have done that.But no movements at all? Do you know why? @Doomenik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position your both icons and span text as `absolute` and then if needed you could use `CSS calc() function` to align them at `top-right` and `bottom-right` above the image.

```css
.playlist {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.playlist img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.playlist .span-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: calc(100% - 98%);
  color: #fff;
}

.playlist .tm {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: calc(100% - 98%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="playlist">
  <span class="span-icon"><i class="fa fa-film"></i></span>
  <span class="tm">2:10</span>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-6.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: How awesome you are..Fantastic..No words for me..Thank you so much :)

Comment: Welcome @Sampath :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="playlist">
  <span class="span-icon"><ion-icon [name]="data.icon"></ion-icon></span>
  <span class="span-text">{{data.text}}</span>
  <img [src]="data.imageUrl" [alt]="data.text" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.span-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
}
.span-icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0;
}
```

You simply set the icons absolute and position it with `top`, `right`. ...

Comment: @Sampath Probably cause your width and height of your playlist element there undefined. Frnt´s solution should work for you